# Finding the limit of a matrix and showing if it exists

Tags: linear-algebra

For the matrix
\[
A=\frac{1}{10}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 7 \\
7 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\]
I try to find the limit of $A^n$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: What exactly are you taking a limit of? You've just written a single matrix.

Comment: It's a 2x2 matrix, the (.7 .1) should go on the bottom

Comment: @user105969 that's what we know. What we don't know is what you mean by taking a limit of a 2x2 matrix

Comment: Yes, but there's still nothing to take a limit of. It's like asking what the limit of $6$ is.

Comment: Ahh of course, i have to take the lim (A^m) as m -> infinity

Comment: If you mean the limit under self-multiplication (infinite power), then: the determinant of a product is the product of determinants of its multiplicands.

Comment: @Jan: Determinants have not been mentioned.

Comment: @JanDvorak as the determinant is continuous you can only see if $\det(A^n)$ diverges that $A^n$ can't be a convergent sequence. But taking for example the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ which has determinant 0 and hence $\det(A^n)=0$ so it surely converges, won't converge at as a matrix.

Answer (score 4):

I would suspect that you're meant to take the limit of $$\begin{pmatrix}.1 & .7\\.7 & .1\end{pmatrix}^n$$ as $n\to\infty.$ One way to do this is to *diagonalize* the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}.1 & .7\\.7 & .1\end{pmatrix},$$ that is, to rewrite as $A=PDP^{-1},$ where $P$ is some invertible $2\times 2$ matrix and $D$ has the form $$D=\begin{pmatrix}d_1 & 0\\0 & d_2\end{pmatrix}.$$ It can be shown by induction that $$A^n=PD^nP^{-1}=P\begin{pmatrix}d_1^n & 0\\0 & d_2^n\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$$ for all $n\ge 1.$ Since matrix multiplication is continuous, then, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n=P\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}D^n\right]P^{-1}.$$

Comment: +1 For taking time to answer such a question. I would have just said obviously both eigenvalues do have absolute value strictly smaller 1 and hence the limit is 0.

Comment: @Xenomorph: A concrete example of *what*, exactly?

Comment: @Xenomorph: Well, first of all, do you know how to find eigenvalues? Second, do you know how to find eigenvectors for a particular eigenvalue?

Comment: @Xenomorph: Good! The idea is to let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be the eigenvalues of $A,$ let the first column of $P$ be an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $d_1,$ and let the second column of $P$ be an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $d_2.$

Comment: @Xenomorph: Because I'd already found the eigenvalues of $A$. ;-) In general, you won't know without checking.

Comment: @Xenomorph: However, $A$ has ***infinitely-many*** eigenvectors associated to each eigenvalue. You just need to pick one non-zero eigenvector for each.

Comment: @Xenomorph: That can still be alright, as long as you can find linearly independent eigenvectors. The upshot is that an $n\times n$ $A$ can be diagonalized like this if and only if there is an $n$-basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are good with guessing eigenvalues there is a a similar way which in this case is kind of more easy.
Because of
\[ \frac{1}{10}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 7 \\ 7 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{4}{5} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\]
and 
\[ \frac{1}{10}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 7 \\ 7 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = -\frac{3}{5} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}\] 
So instead of calculating the limit of $A^n$, I look at the limit of $A^n \cdot v$ for any $v$. 
As the geometric sequence $q^n$ converges to zero iff $|q|<1$ we see that here $A^n\cdot v$ converges
to zero for any $v$. Hence $A^n$ must converge to zero.